# C++, how can I make an array with length not limited to an integer?

Tags: c++, arrays

Currently, C++ only allows declaring arrays with length as integers. Is there any way to get around it? I am trying to create a program that generates an array that can potentially reach thousands or even millions in length depending on input, but array declaration limiting to integer-only length is holding me back.

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590423/c-how-can-i-make-an-array-with-length-not-limited-to-an-integer#comment115966274_65590423) Basically, supposing that I want to create a 2d array with 5 rows and 500,000 columns, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Why do you think that "integer" would limit you from having millions in length?

Comment: Do you mean you want an array size greater than can fit in an `int`? Best to clarify that, since *integers* can be as large as you want.

Comment: @cigien “*integers can be as large as you want*” - up to a max limit, though.

Comment: Sorry, I ought to have been more specific. Basically, supposing that I want to create a 2d array with 5 rows and 500,000 collumns, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm trying to point out that integers are infinite, and the constraints are physical limits of the system.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, instead of as a comment.

Comment: @AlexEliotOfficial sure, that can happen if you are trying to put that huge array in automatic memory with a small finite size, like the stack. Use dynamic memory instead, then it will work just fine.

Comment: Unless your array elements are particularly huge, 2.5 M elements in an array (whether 1D or 2D) is easily achievable on 32-bit systems if available memory is sufficient.  Practically, it will often be better to use dynamically allocated memory (e.g. an array of five `std::vector<element>` each of which can by dynamically resized to 500000 elements).    There is, however, a design question - the most common reason people want large arrays is that they default to having all of "something" in memory at once - which, realistically, can often be avoided.

Answer (score 9):

The prototype for `std::array` is

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> struct array;
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t,

> `std::size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible
> object of any type (including array). **A type whose size cannot be
> represented by `std::size_t` is ill-formed** (since C++14)

(emphasis mine)

So C++, by definition, cannot express the concept of an object whose size is larger than a `std::size_t`.

Fortunately, on most platforms `std::size_t` is going to be 32 bits at a minimum, meaning it can reach not only millions but billions.  And if you're on a platform where it's smaller than that then presumably your hardware isn't physically capable of storing larger objects anyway.

---

**UPDATE:** In the comments you add

> Sorry, I ought to have been more specific. Basically, supposing that I
> want to create a 2d array with 5 rows and 500,000 columns, I get a
> segmentation fault.

If the problem here were a limitation of the *language*, you would get a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Since you're getting a runtime error, the problem is with your platform, not the language.  In this particular case, the "problem" is that it doesn't give you enough stack space to support multi-megabyte objects in a stack frame.  (This is a pretty sensible limitation, if you ask me.)  Instead, you'll want to allocate your data on the heap.

I could hand you some code that would just make your problem go away for now, but what you really need to do is read about the stack and heap and understand what they are and how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue as opposed to just showing working code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n]; // dynamic declaration of variable length array
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cin >> arr[i]; // read array elements
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: For 2d array

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int **arr;
    int r, c;
    std::cin >> r >> c;

    // Create an array of row heads
    arr = new int *[r];

    // Create an 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) arr[i] = new int[c];

    // read input in 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) std::cin >> arr[i][j];

    // print 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. First, you should add some explanation rather than just showing code. Second, this is not a good C++ practice (you even don't delete). A vector of vectors would be much better. Or, if efficiency matters, I would always store 2D array elements in a 1D array only in some order (row-wise, column-wise, Z-Morton, etc.) and possibly wrap it with some class with element accessors.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector`is a better choice. You only need `push_back` or `emplace_back`to add element into it.

More details:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/